# Getting POST data from form created in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm a bit stuck with my code...
I'm building an application where a user can create boards(or collections) of earlier posted items. After creation of the board, the user gets directed to the board detail page, where the user then gets to choose an item recently posted. The live preview is created trough an Ajax request.
I'd like to complete this feature by clicking the checkbox and then inserting the data received into the database, like a form request.

The Live preview PHP:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT items.Url, items.id, items.Beschrijving 
FROM Items WHERE items.user_id = $userID AND items.id = $postID");
$result = $sql->execute();
```

I tried doing something like this within the live preview page, but it's not displaying. Instead, the page seems to reload. No errors found in the console either.

```
if(isset($_POST['addBoard'])){
echo "TEST";
}
```

Rest of the live preview page:

```
print "<table>";
while($row = $sql->fetch()){
  print '<tr>
        <td class="well well-lg">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <h4 style="margin-left:5%;">'.$row['Beschrijving'].'</h4>
        <a href="detail.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img name="myimage" 
        src="'.$row['Url'].'" alt="Image" style="width:200px;" /></a>
        <label></label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxAdd" />Voeg 
        dit item toe aan uw bord</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
        name="submit">Toevoegen aan board</button>
        </form>
        </td>
      </tr>';
}
print "</table>";
echo '</pre>';
```

Live preview script.JS:

```
$("#sel1").on("change", function(){
function clearpost(){
$("#results").val("");
}

var selected = $(this).val();
makeAjaxRequest(selected);
function makeAjaxRequest(postID){
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  data:{postID},
  url:"itemOverview.php",
  datatype: "text/json",
  success:function(res){
    $("#results").html("<p>Uw items : " + res + "</p>");
    }
  })
 }
})
```

Any feedback is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: too much code here, please post the code that is giving you problems

Comment: Anything in the console? And rename the name="submit" to something else

Comment: What is error? seems like error with your AJAX code, data might not submitting.

Comment: I edited my post with the essence of the problem, I'm not getting any errors in the console either.  

mplungjan I edited the name to 'addBoard'

Comment: Shouldn't the `datatype` be `application/json` instead of `text/json`? Also, you're not encoding the data with `json_encode` in your PHP.

Comment: Not sure what data to encode? The data displayed in php page is retrieved via sql, or am I missing something?

Comment: Check what `$row` returns after `while($row = $sql->fetch()){...` using `print json_encode($row);`

Comment: Isnt javascript case sensitive? datatype or dataType?

Comment: @lkdhruw this is what I get   {"Url":"https:\/\/miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/images\/thumbnail-facebook\/1485938697.4579_4Upy7U_n.jpg","0":"https:\/\/miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/images\/thumbnail-facebook\/1485938697.4579_4Upy7U_n.jpg","id":"76","1":"76","Beschrijving":"9gag","2":"9gag"}

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is but here are few remarks: (1) your use of functions within your `onchange` event handler is so not needed (2) you seem to using PDO [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) wrong as you are not using any parameter markers (3) in your AJAX code, `data` should be a key-value pair e.g. `data:{ 'addBoard': postID}`

Answer (score 0):

Can't able to find the exact problem but here is the working code of mine. I hope this may help you.

```
if($sql->execute()){
    $rows = $sql->fetchAll();
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $row["id"];
        ...
```